# Assert Failing. Cannot Determine Why?

Tags: testing, automation, testng, assert

I have the following code.

```
String rowNum = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min);
WebElement randomRow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+rowNum+"]/td/div/input")); 
Assert.assertEquals(randomRow.getAttribute("checked").equals("checked"), "checked", "YES is not selected");
```

Basically randomRow is a random row from a table and I am checking the first column which has a radio button in it. The radio button should have the attribute of checked= "checked".

When the test hits the assert it is failing with the following:

```
YES is not selected expected [checked[ but found ]false]
```

Any thoughts on why this assertion is failing?

Comment: Is this Java and Selenium?

Comment: Yes it is Java and Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assert is failing because you are comparing the identity of two objects, a boolean and a string.  You should either be comparing a boolean or a string.

This

```
randomRow.getAttribute("checked").equals("checked")
```

returns a boolean, and you're comparing it against the string "checked".  Your assertion should be:

If you want to check that the row has the attribute "checked", you can write your assert more concisely like this:

```
Assert.assertEquals(randomRow.getAttribute("checked"), "checked", "YES is not selected");
```

Comment: I did that and it still fails. Says "YES is not selected expected [true[ but found ]false]"

Comment: I suspect that is your test actually failing now because the object isn't checked.  What is the output of System.out.println(randomRow.getAttribute("checked"))

Comment: If you're using firebug, can you also verify that the attribute is "checked" (lowercase c) and not "Checked" (uppercase C)

Comment: The attribute is "checked" in firebug, however the System.out.println(randomRow.getAttribut("checked")) revealed that the value is "true". Thanks for suggesting that.